# Space in credentials file, smbfs & fstab

Tags: ubuntu, samba, fstab

I'm trying to mount a Windows share on an Ubuntu Server box.  It works with smbmount, and with an entry in /etc/fstab.

```
//Kubrick/Projects    /mnt/projects    smbfs    user=Eric\040Fritz%{pass},rw    0    0
```

However, when I try to write a credentials file, it always give me a "Permission Denied" error when I try to `mount /mnt/projects`.  Here is the creds file and the new fstab line.

```
username=Eric Fritz
password={pass}
```

.

```
//Kubrick/Projects    /mnt/projects    smbfs    credentials=/root/.creds,rw    0    0
```

What is the proper way to escape the space in the username when using a credentials file?

Comment: [`smbfs` is deprecated.](http://www.samba.org/samba/smbfs/) Try **`cifs`** instead.

Comment: For some reason, cifs didn't work before - now it does.  If you want to change your comment to an answer I can accept it ;)